# In vaadin 22 grid Items are not getting selected when select all check box is clicked on UI

Tags: java-8, vaadin22

I am using vaadin 22 grid with lazy loading. When I click on select all checkbox of grid, no item is selected except select-all checkbox on ui. While  debugging the code I obeserved that in grid selection listener, selected item size is equal to the number of items in grid. But on ui the selection for all the item is not reflected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide useful examples of your issue and solutions you've tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You have most likely a problem with object identity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks You Guys for the inputs,
Resolved the issue after adding equals and hashcode methods in dto object which are used as a data in Grid.